# How to assign value of another key from same Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, assign

How to assign value of another key->value from same array in PHP?

```
$arr = array(
    "level" => 5,
    "spd"   => $this->level * 24,
);
```

I tried and this way too

```
$arr = array(
    "level" => 5,
    "spd"   => function() {
        return $this->level * 24,
    },
);
```

Both doesnt work.

Comment: You can't do it this way. Only in two distinct statements.

Comment: Can you produce a minimum verifiable example? They look ok to me except for certain keywords and syntax mistake that you did https://3v4l.org/7q7dB

Comment: $this is only available in class context for instantiated objects, you used array() language construct, and $this is not available magically there. With this statement $arr is defined at the end. You can do this like this: 
$arr["level"] = 5;
$arr["spd"] = $arr['level'] * 24;
Or one line above you just wrote level is 5, so why can you just do 'spd' => 5 * 24 ?